# Probability of values smaller/greater than mean not 50%?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, chi-squared-distribution

I'm just starting to work with Chi-Squared distributions and I'm having a hard time understanding why P(X>µ) <> P(X<µ) <> 0.5.

If my expected value is k, why is the chance of getting a higher or lower result not the same?

My concrete example was a confidence interval for a ND variance - if we make the size of the CI smaller and smaller, why doesn't it end up on s² rather than s²/Chi²_0.5 (which only for for infinte DGF ends up being the same)?

Comment: The _mean_ is the expected value. The _median_ is the value that splits the probability into two equal parts. For symmetric distributions they are the same, but for asymmetric distributions, such as the Chi-squared, they are not.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense... But I can't quite comprehend how a "0% CI" doesn't converge on the expected value, is there any easy way to imagine that? How can the expected value be outside the confidence interval?

Comment: Can't help you on confidence intervals. I don't like them and don't use them. I take a Bayesian approach instead. Sorry.

Comment: Can you show us your calculations, then we can see where you go wrong.